# Can't start MySQL Error 1067

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1067

I'm facing with one stange error with MySQL

Mysqld.exe --console says:

`mysqld.exe --console`

`mysqld.exe: Character set 'utb8_general_ci' is not a compiled character set and`
`is not specified in the 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\share\charsets\`
`Index.xml' file`

`120524  8:49:51 [ERROR] Aborting`

`120524  8:49:51 [Note] mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete`

How I can fix this charset problem?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'utf8_general_ci'`? Is there some sort of error in your `my.ini`?

Comment: Yes, I have typed it incorecticly, sorry :)

Comment: So, did you solve your problem or it was just a typo in your answer?

Comment: I solved :) How I can give you points and delete this stupid question?

Comment: if you want, you can accept the answer I've just posted; to delete your question, you could ask moderators, but why? Maybe someone does your same mistake and find here solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mispelled something in `my.ini`: it should be `utf8_general_ci`.
Correct this and restart MySql.